# Jquery Smooth Scroll Using Offset.top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I'm attempting to create a smooth scrolling effect from a `topNav` to various sections on a webpage. In the code below, I've recreated the issue I'm having, which is simply I can't seem to have the scroll process animated.  My links jump to the proper sections, and I've `console.logged` along the way to make sure the proper elements are being grabbed at the time of the `'click'` but it is still not working.

Can anyone assist? Initially I thought it might have to do with the fact that instead of giving the `navlinks` individual IDs, I grouped them with a class name.  Could that be part of my problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('.slide').click(function() {
  
  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  
  $('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(link).offset().top}, 1000);
  return false;
  
  
  
  
 });
 
 
 
});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 120px;
}

div {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <a href="#first" class="slide">Section 1</a>
 <a href="#second" class="slide">Section 2</a>
 <a href="#third" class="slide">Section 3</a>
 <a href="#fourth" class="slide">Section 4</a>
</nav>

<div>
 <a name="first">Section 1</a>
</div>

<div>
 <a name="second">Section 2</a>
</div>

<div>
 <a name="third">Section 3</a> 
</div>

<div>
 <a name="fourth">Section 4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, did you load JQuery in your project?

If so, you made a little mistake in your HTML. Href attribute reference an ID, not a name attribute !

My solution :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('.slide').click(function() {
  
  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(link).offset().top}, 1000);
  return false; 
 });
});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 120px;
}

div {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <a href="#first" class="slide">Section 1</a>
 <a href="#second" class="slide">Section 2</a>
 <a href="#third" class="slide">Section 3</a>
 <a href="#fourth" class="slide">Section 4</a>
</nav>

<div id="first">
 <a>Section 1</a>
</div>

<div id="second">
 <a>Section 2</a>
</div>

<div id="third">
 <a>Section 3</a> 
</div>

<div id="four">
 <a>Section 4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I do have it loaded.  Ah! Thank you so much for your solution.